# Auth0 will soon be sponsoring InfoSec

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) will be sponsoring InfoSec beginning September 14 through January 31, 2022. We wanted to give you a heads up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in the top right header of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: auth0 homepage with sponsorship mockup]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making InfoSec successful.

Comment: As someone not familiar with this system, how does this work? There is money somehow involved, where does it come from and where does it go?

Comment: The sites are free to us to use, but they still have a lot of costs associated for things like hosting, uptime, multi-site availability, etc. While SO has ads, and there's a jobsite (which charges posters for posting), and Teams, this is another revenue generation avenue. The money goes to paying for features, uptime, etc.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe Based on my understanding of several other sites operating under this system, it's a permanent, not-too-obtrusive ad (a non-animated logo) that sits in the top right of all pages. That's it. It's literally just a permanent ad spot. If you want to know the *specific details* of how much SE, Inc gets paid, whether it's per-impression, etc., you'd have to ask on MSE, but I don't think they publicly reveal that information.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe: AWS pays Stack Exchange, Inc. In exchange, there'll be a small "Sponsored by:" message in the top right of the site that links to the sponsor's website.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe Where does it come from cotton eye joe?

Comment: Is it intentional that when I block tracking cookies, the sponsor's logo disappears? That's a nifty feature, if nothing else.

Comment: Auth0 extended their sponsorship to January 31. I updated the post to reflect the new end date.

Comment: The newest post about site sponsorship is here: [What goes into site sponsorships on SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376530/282094) - perhaps it would be useful to edit that link into this announcement.

Comment: The subsequent announcement: [Auth0 will soon be sponsoring InfoSec again](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/67458)

Answer (score 2):

## Update

The sponsorship has ended.  It always had a scheduled duration.  The content I wrote during the sponsorship follows the break, for historical purposes.

---

## I don't like it.

> [image: new header of site, says sponsored by auth0]

> [image: zoomed out screenshot of the site]

Reminder: StackExchange is nothing without the community.

Comment: My first issue is that it implies that somehow the users here have allowed it.  Some newbie CIO might think that means that we endorse Auth0.  Other than "don't roll your own crypto", we don't endorse *anything* right?

Comment: I keep the majority of my answers technology-neutral. "You should implement a solution, which has the following characteristics", rather than "You should buy the following product."

Comment: My second issue is that since the "auth0" text is the **largest font on the screen**, someone who has never visited before would be forgiven for thinking this site is named auth0, or that it is owned by auth0.