# Is Auth0 sponsoring us again?

Tags: discussion, bug, site-sponsorship

Auth0 was supposed to be sponsoring us [from September to January 31, 2022](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3456/235964). The sponsorship had duly ended, but I've noticed that the Auth0 logo has appeared again. Is this a bug, or did Auth0 start sponsoring us again? If so, why were we not informed beforehand?

[image]

Comment: Logo seems to have disappeared now, I guess it was just a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auth0 will be sponsoring the site again beginning on April 21st. I just [posted the announcement](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/auth0-will-soon-be-sponsoring-infosec-again). It went live by accident earlier than it was supposed to. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The logo is gone now, so it was probably just a bug. The timing of this bug (and perhaps fix as well) seems to have coincided with this network-wide bug: [Every site just turned blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377950/906149). Although I cannot see why a CSS bug would cause the Auth0 logo to appear, they may have been related.