# Auth0 will soon be sponsoring InfoSec again

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

[Auth0](https://auth0.com/) had [previously sponsored InfoSec](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/auth0-will-soon-be-sponsoring-infosec) from September 2021 to January 2022. We are excited to announce that they will be sponsoring InfoSec once again from **April 21 to December 31, 2022**. [As some of you noticed](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3476/485), the sponsorship went live for a couple of hours and was then turned off again; this was an accident, and we apologize. It's our goal to give communities as much of a heads-up as we can when a sponsorship is going to go live.

When the banner does go live again, it will look as it did during the previous sponsorship.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown on the right side of the banner at the top of the site, in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: sponsorship mock up]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and Auth0 wishing to sponsor InfoSec again speaks volumes to the work you've put into building a thriving community. Thank you.

Comment: See also Rosie's more recent MSE post: [What goes into site sponsorships on SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376530/335251)

Comment: I really do wish you would make the "sponsored by" a bit more prominent. It currently looks like it has been designed to be missed by new users.

Comment: @nobody That may be by design. You don't want to drive new users away with sponsorships in their face